# web_components in dartium

Tags: dart, angular-dart, web-component

I had some trouble to display my project in FF cause of shadow_dom. I read that the shadow_dom package is deprecated so I followed the steps in http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web_components and added web_components to my project.

Now I can build and run my project in FF. However when I include packages/web_components/platform.js and run my project in dartium it displays without css whereever I use shadow_dom. I also get the following error :

> ShadowDOMPolyfill polyfill was loaded in Dartium. This will not work.
>   This indicates that Dartium's Chrome version is not compatible with
>   this version of web_components.

How to solve this ?

Comment: The same issue was reported several months ago for Dartium 34. https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18475 What Dart version are you using?

Comment: Dart: 1.4.3. I "solved" it by making a script which only includes packages/web_components/platform.js if the browser is not dartium but it feels like there must exist a better approach..

Comment: I would also like to know if angular is dependent on web_components (as of .14)?  The script is listed in the index.html file but but not pulled with angular.  Everything works in chrome and ff so I am guessing that it is no longer a relevant polyfill?